# Events being fired twice

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle

Given a function and a event in a contract:

```
event OtherCreated(address other, address addr1, address addr2);

function doSomething(address addr1, address addr2){
     if(aBool == true){
        address other = new OtherContract(addr1, addr2);
        others.push(other);
        OtherCreated(other, addr1, addr2);
     }
}
```

And given a js call in a browser:

```
 .then(function(tx_id){
      console.log('previous call completed');
     otherCreated = contractAddr.OtherCreated();
     otherCreated.watch(function(error, result){
        if (!error)
        {
          console.log('in event handler');            
        }
      return  contractAddr.doSomething(account0, account1, {from: account0, gas: 4700000 });
    })
```

The event handler is called twice. Is this an error on my part, or do I need to change something in this setup.

[image]

Output:

Comment: Is this `.then` part a success callback?

Comment: Yes. When I put an extra log in the then handler I can see that that part is executed once but the event twice.

Comment: I think `contract.watch` is global, you don't have to use it with callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in my code, obviously. Be careful when you create your event handlers. Listening to events directly after the contract was created and not chaining along solved the issue.

Comment: What do you mean not chaining along?

Answer (score 0):

I've coded up a utility function to filter events by name, arguments etc. Answered in a different question:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/21661/7132